# Find value by Hour between two Time frames in Excel

Tags: excel, time

Every employee in my spreadsheet has an entry for every activity they do throughout the day with a Start and End time. **`(mmm d, yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM format)`**  Some of the start and stop times are across multiple hours.

Example:

If an employee is in an activity with a Start time of 6:15am and an end time of 817am, I want it the 6am column to read .25, the 7am column to read 1, and the 8am column to read .28

Not sure if its possible. [Records tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCTa6.png)

[image]

On my spreadsheet I have two tabs, Records and Hour. 
On the records tab: C5 has an activity, D5 has a start time, E5 has an end time.

Hour tab: E7 is 12am, F7 is 1am, etc.

Comment: Why wouldn't the 6:00am column read `0.75` instead of `0.25`?

Answer (score 0):

Nice small problem to have a fun with in the evening... one way to tackle this is brute-force evaluation of the start and end time with regards to the specific hour, like I've done here (with comments):

[image: Time table]

[image: Time table with formulas]

Note that this won't work for the time spans crossing the day boundary; for that to work, you'll have to re-consider the cutting-the-date-away part.